# Error: top picklist missing

Tags: picklist, visual-workflow, dependent-picklist

I am using the flow builder to create a three level dependency among three Pick-lists; however, I am getting the following error message(check screenshot too):

```
Error: top picklist missing
```

I am using the screen component "Dependent Picklist". My configuration for the screen component as follows:

```
API Name: Test
Object API Name: Delivery__c
Picklist 1 API Name: {!CountryPickList}
Picklist 2 API Name: {!ConnectionTypePickList}
Picklist 3 API Name: {!CarrierTypePickList}
Picklist 1 Label: {!CountryPickList}
Picklist 2 Label: {!ConnectionTypePickList}
Picklist 3 Label: {!CarrierTypePickList}
Picklist 1 Value: {!CountryPickList}
Picklist 2 Value: {!ConnectionTypePickList}
Picklist 3 Value: {!CarrierTypePickList}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a standard flow component for dependent picklists as of Winter '19. Check out this video on how to create a dependent picklist. https://youtu.be/FSQ52gVOgcY

Salesforce Documentation https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_screencmp_dependentpicklists.htm&type=5 https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_screen_dependentpicklists.htm